# Plotting Ellipse in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In addition to my R programming course, I am also taking an intro to LaTeX course. We have a new assignment which is to generate a graph of a given function (in Matlab), save it and then recall it in LaTeX code as though we're making a publication. My Matlab is a little rusty, and I don't think that I quite got the code right. Furthermore it doesn't look anything like the example we were given for reference. The function that we were asked to plot is the following: 1 = x^(2)/9 - y^(2)/4

What my image is supposed to look like:
[image: What my image is supposed to look like:]

What my Matlab code generated:
[image: What my Matlab code generated:]

```
function graph_1

clc; clear all; 

a = 9;
b = 4;
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
t = -pi:0.1:pi;
x = 1 - x0 + a*cos(t);
y = 1 - y0 + a*sin(t);

figure(1); clf; 
    
plot(x,y,'b','linewidth',1)
set(gca, 'fontsize', 12)
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
grid on

end
```

Once I get the code to run in Matlab, I get a weird looking ellipse and it doesn't look "pretty" like the one my professors gave us as reference which I have attached. The full assignment is asking us to generate a plot with our programming language of choice, save it, and then have the LaTeX code actually recall the file and then insert into a pdf. How would I export this figure to somehwere else in my computer?

Comment: (1) Your ellipse parameters are wrong, hence the size doesn't match; you also don't use `b` in your computation. (2) Your `t` doesn't end with the same angle it starts with, hence the gap; use `linspace` instead. (3) Add `axis equal` after plotting so that the aspect ratio is correct. (4) Use `print` to export as PDF (check the docs). (5) Don't ever use `clear all`, but especially not inside a function! `clear` by itself clears all variables, but at the start of your function you don't have any variables to clear.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I just noticed that I never used b in my code. Could you please explain what you meant by me using the wrong parameters for my ellipse?

Comment: You‘ve got `a=9`, should probably be 3.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, also what would I use for my arguments in the linspace function?

Comment: You can type `help linspace` to get documentation, or `doc linspace` to get more elaborate documentation. Or just look online: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks for all your help! I managed to fix my code and then I got the ellipse I needed to plot! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mehmet please post an answer showing your final working code, to indicate that this problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I thought I needed to plot an ellipse, but found that I actually needed to plot a hyperbola. At any rate, I figured out how to plot both functions, because their format is nearly identical, and have included the code for the ellipse. In my experience, the best way to plot these functions was to use the `fimplicit` function in Matlab. To fully understand how it works, I strongly suggest typing `help fimplicit` into the command window. From there, you can see the documentation and examples of how to plot functions like these.

This is the code I ran in Matlab to make things work correctly.

```
function graph_1

clc; clear; 

f1 = @(x,y) x.^(2)/9 + y.^(2)/4 - 1;

fimplicit(f1, 'b');
grid on;
axis equal;

print(figure(1), '-dpng') %% Saves a picture of the image in png format. 

end
```

And then this is the ellipse I generated:

[image: Plot of an Ellipse.]

Comment: It looks a little bit cutoff at the edges, but thats because I didn't use the `axis equal` function in my plotting section. I also noticed that the original equation that was assigned was one for a hyperbola and not an ellipse. The code still works the same, you would only need to change the + sign in the f1 variable to get a hyperbola.

Comment: You may find `xlim()` and `ylim()` useful